# Add ListItem to a Field of type List<MyClass> using Reflection

Tags: c#, collections, system.reflection

I have the following problem:
I want to Add a List item to a Collection to a field of a class.

To be clear: 
I have a class:

```
class MyClass {
   List<MyStruct> myList1;
   List<MyStruct> myList2;
}

struct MyStruct {
   string foo { get; set; }
   string bar { get; set; }
}
```

What i want is to add a MyStruct to the List myList1 by getting the field through:

```
MyClass blub = new MyClass();
(blub.GetType().GetField("myList1") as List<MyStruct>).Add(new Mystruct {
      foo = "foo";
      bar = "bar";
   });
```

Is there a possibility to achieve this in any way?
The main problem is that i have to identify my field by a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Reflection you need to specify the `BindingFlags` to retrieve private fields. When you get it, you need to use `FieldInfo.SetValue` and `FieldInfo.GetValue`. Like this:

```
MyClass blub = new MyClass();

var field = blub.GetType().GetField("myList1", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
List<MyStruct> value = field.GetValue(blub) as List<MyStruct>;

if (value == null)
    value = new List<MyStruct>();

value.Add(new MyStruct { foo = "foo", bar = "bar" });

field.SetValue(blub, value);
```

Note that you need to modify the properties of your struct to be public :

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public string foo { get; set; }
    public string bar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The clue was to do a get value to get the list.
and then Set the value again to the field.

Thanks!